# Why are these seemingly unnecessary merges happening in git?

Tags: git, branching, merging

Consider this screenshot from our development repository:

[image: Branching]

We are relatively new to git, so things are still somewhat confusing. The question at hand: If you take a look at the commits by me at the very top; are confusing to us. Why do I need to merge something if I didn't even branch anything?

I commited the `adjust buildpath` commit, and after that, git immediately made me do a merge. but with what? The `invitation` branch is not interesting for me, and I never touched it in any way.

Where did this `anonymous` blue branch come from and why? My colleague (blue avatar) only works in the `invitation` branch currently.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening in git-layman terms (as I said, we are new to this)?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: Did you then push the commit dev repository?

Comment: @gnat Do you mean to say this is the wrong place or is that just a common comment for any git question?

Comment: @Trengot I mostly commit immediately, yes

Comment: per my reading of that guidance this appears to be a question for SO

Comment: @FlorianPeschka, there is a difference between committing and pushing. When you commit, you add your changes to your local repo - no merging necessary. When you then push that commit to a central location, it has to be merged with the current state of the branch. In this case the "removed duplicate..." and "moved user..." commits had been pushed since you last pulled (updated your local repo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the site [Visualizing Git Concepts with D3](http://www.wei-wang.com/ExplainGitWithD3/#) very helpful to see how the tree will look when various git commands are done from various states.

Lets back track to the `Disabled mail delivery...` commit.

The next commit was on the invitation branch done by Red as origin/master was merged into that.

Unfortunately teal was still on the master branch and did two commits on master - `Removed duplicate imports...` and `Moved user routes...` which were then merged into invitation again by red.

Now, you were also working on what *you* had locally as master and did the `adjust buildpath` commit.  However, when trying to push this some where it said that your master was out of sync with the remote - and it was.  Master on remote was at `Moved user routes` and thus you had to merge the remote back into what you had.

`git merge` also does a commit when it does its merge.

From the D3 link at the top, the git merge is very close to the state you had at the `adjust buildpath` commit.  Doing `git merge master` in your tree is much like doing a `git merge dev` in the D3 sandbox:

[image: Initial state]

And then a `git merge dev` brings us to:

[image]

Commit `e065536...` is exactly like your `Merge branch 'master' of https://...` in this case.

But what if you don't *want* to have those commits.  Some people don't like them (personally, I do... but that is my preference).

Then, you are looking at `git rebase`

This will reapply the commits from one branch on another.

[image: Initial state]

Note again the very similar structure as the merge example (note: I've checked out master rather than leave it on dev).  And then a `git rebase dev` brings everything into line *without* the additional commit.

[image: After rebase]

Note that the commit `bb92e0e` which *was* the old master head is now greyed out and the *new* master head is `decfd13` because the history is reapplied on top of what you have done.

There's a gotcha there.  You are rewriting your local history when you do a rebase.  If you have shared the state of your repo (pushing it to somewhere else) where commit `bb92e0e` is out there, rebasing will confuse everyone.  If you have to do a `git push --force`, you're probably doing it wrong.

Note that when you do a `git pull`, you are doing the commands `git fetch` and `git merge` - thus the additional commit.  You can do a `git pull --rebase` which will be a rebase rather than a merge for the second step (you can also tweak your git config to do this by default).  You can play with this a bit in the D3 site 'git pull' example.

Note that the convention on your tree appears to be `pull` and `merge` rather than `rebase` - it may be best to keep following that convention and just understand (and accept) where the commits are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer in git layman terms: your teal colleague is mistaken if they think they were only working on the 'invitation' branch. They were committing + pushing to master, and only then merging back to invitation.